# Why I can't write files using php in xampp?

Tags: php, windows, file, xampp

I'm using xampp in Windows for local developing environment. I tried to create a simple logger which appends to a text file.

```
function Logger ($logmessage)
{
    $filename = '/errorlog-' . date('Ymd') . '.txt';
    file_put_contents($filename, $logmessage, FILE_APPEND | LOCK_EX);
}
```

I've tried to echo the `$filename`, and it says `'/errorlog-20140427.txt'` which means it already has valid filename (I think).

But when I call this logger function, there's no error raised, but I can't find the file everywhere. I tried to search for the whole htdocs for `*.txt` but no files found. Do you know why I can't write file using php? Do I need to use `fopen` first? As I refer to another help, I can just use `file_put_contents` directly without `fopen`. Thanks for the help.

Comment: check your ERROR log for your webserver

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're trying to write to the root of your filesystem, e.g.

```
$file = '/error-log-' etc...
```

is essentially the same as

```
$file = 'c:/error-log' etc...
```

The webserver account is highly unlikely to have the rights to do anything in `C:\`.

If you'd bothered checking the return value of file_put_contents, you'd have seen it was returning a boolean false to indicate failure.

Comment: yes return false. but I don't know what error it is until you just told me. then how if I want to write to the base path of my site? for example d:/xampp/htdocs ?

Comment: then do something like `$file = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "/error-log"` or whatever.

Comment: oh okay, thanks, that's what I really need. I don't know how to phrase the kind of query on google to go to article containing about this 'DOCUMENT_ROOT' index var. Thank you very much.